# Setup chef server custom URL

Tags: chef-infra

I want to install chef server on the same server with zabbix and make zabbix use chef embedded nginx instead of apache. In the result I want to access zabbix web ui through `https://hostname/zabbix` and chef web ui with `https://hostname/chef`.

I found how to configure nginx for zabbix, but I can't figure out how to configure chefs' URL.

Comment: Which version of chef server are you talking about ? You'll have more than the webui to redirect and to manage the chef clients url too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported as far as I know. You could manually rework the nginx proxy configs, but the next time you upgrade Chef Server or run `reconfigure` it would be wiped out. Best bet would be to move Chef's nginx to a high port and build your own proxy config on top of it. This won't work with the the web interface though.